# Changing Maxclient setting in php heroku

Tags: php, heroku, apache2, config

I am new to heroku,i am getting the below warning in server logs. I have just uploaded my php scripts into the heroku through git I am not sure where my Maxclient setting is present too..

> server reached MaxClients setting, consider raising the MaxClients settings

I saw in many posts to chnage Maxclients in httd.conf. I am not aware of the apache server folder sturucture. Can you please let me know in which path should i keep the httd.conf and also the format of it. You can also direct me to any posts which explains it well

Comment: i found the answer.. followed the usage instructions in https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php

Answer (score 0):

i found the answer.. followed the usage instructions in github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-php
and my php code was found to be /app
Later created httd.conf file inside /app/apche/conf

Comment: `/app/apache/conf` doesn't do anything in the new buildpack. Are you sure you are not on the `#legacy` branch of the buildpack? You shouldn't be hitting MaxClients limits; the new Apache uses mpm_event and a pretty high MaxClients setting.

Comment: How can i check whether i am using legacy branch of build pack ? wer can i check the mpm_event ?

Comment: Just `heroku config:get BUILDPACK_URL`. No need to do anything about `mpm_event`, it's the default.